# $product->name variable not processed correctly in Magento Bestsellers module

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I'm having a issue with my Magento not displaying the Best Selling products module because it doesn't seem to be processing the *$product->name* variable correctly.

The relevant code in mostpopular.phtml is:

```
<?php if($counter <= $totalPerPage): ?>

<?php $productUrl =  $product->getProductUrl() ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $productUrl ?>" title="View <?php echo $product->name ?>">
      <?php echo $product->name ?>
    </a>
</li>
<?php endif; $counter++; ?>
```

And then the HTML output is as below. The problem is the Title parameter in the < a> tag is missing the product name, and there is nothing between the < a>< /a> tags:

`<a href="http://mysite.com/correct-product-url-is-here-and-working-correctly.html" title="View ">              </a>`

Site is running Magento 1.4.1.1

I don't work full-time on this stuff, so it's a bit above my head sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$product->getName()` instead of `$product->name`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either. (And yes, caches are disabled)

Comment: Could you please post the output of `get_class($product)` and `var_dump($product->getData()`?

Comment: I can't find `mostpopular.phtml` in my 1.4.1.1 installation, is it a custom template?

Comment: @JonathanDevere-Ellery have you replaced BOTH the instances of `$product->name` as Oleg said in this answer?